# Dynamic Border configuration in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using drag and drop functionality in an application and I need to change the look of a Grid based on the location of the drag point.

For example, I would like to be able to call something like the following that would change the border to only show the bottom, or the top,etc. This example would be that when there is a drag operation performed over Grid, the top border of the grid would be the only one set to a thickness of 5 and would be black.

```
private void Grid_DragOver(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
{
        Grid grid = (Grid)sender;
        Border border = new Border();
        border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0,5,0,0);
        border.Child = grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Edit: Border color http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderbrush.aspx

Comment: this works, but is there a way to change the color of the margin such as the example above?

Comment: The BorderBrush property relates to a border object, it would not affect the Margin which is what the first link is referring to. Please correct my if I am misunderstanding, or looked over the solution.